# A greenish blue patch in the sky during sunset

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing

I observed a greenish blue patch in the red sky after sunset, and it stayed for not more than 5 minutes. It didn't curve or appear distorted; it was just like a carpet. Why is it so? Could it have been an aurora?

Thank you

**location:** 9° N, 78° E; Temperature 35 deg C.

[image]

Comment: What was the shape, if any? Sunset sky can appear greenish for a short time due to refraction being stronger than usually.

Comment: it was a definite rectangular patch between reddish sky. can such sort of refraction take place-just surrounding red and a definite green? could it be due to some odd atmospheric gas combo?

Comment: What I had in mind appears around the sun's setting position. Interesting.

Comment: Not aurora, not at 9 degrees north of the equator.

Comment: A cloud containing lots of water can look green against a red sky when backlit by the setting sun. http://optics.kulgun.net/Cloud-Colour/ This seems to fit with the general observation. If correct, this is a meteorological phenomenon

Comment: Perhaps it was your eye creating a green after-image of the red sunset. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afterimage) for an example.

Comment: Just curious, is that a view of the sky from above or below? Which way is north or south?

Comment: It's unlikely, but it MAY have been a "green flash": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_flash